# How can I sync structs across multiple IDA databases?

Tags: ida

I am reversing a few modules which share many c++ classes.  I am currently maintaining a single header file which contains every struct definition from each database.  I update this using a produced header file after working on a module.  I then import it when I begin working on a separate module.  This approach is error prone, and I have lost some progress by mistakenly overwriting modified structs in different databases.

Is it possible to configure IDA Pro to read and write to a single struct definition file across multiple databases?    If not, what would be a best practice for this type of situation?

Comment: I would love to have such a feature. Unfortunately, today it isn't possible. I have the very same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try extending [this plugin](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/227/Structure_Dump) which already implements the export and import part of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to configure IDA to do it.

The best simple practice for this that I can imagine is using source control tools such as git or svn for storing exported files.